# KeyBinding for gestures CTRL+C and CTRL+ V do not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, key-bindings

I have a few ICommands in my View Model which I would like to bind them using Key Board bindings to my user control. The problem I am facing is that they are not fired when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to bind my copy and paste commands in my UserControl. Am I supposed to override them or something?.

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+C" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Comment: If you change the Gesture to "CTRL+N" for example, does it work?

Comment: @SuperOli Yes, It does but I have to use commonly known commands for copy and paste.

Comment: Have you tried using `CommandBindings`? Like this:     `<UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Cut" CanExecute="Cut_CanExecute" Executed="Cut_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="Copy" CanExecute="Copy_CanExecute" Executed="Copy_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="Paste" CanExecute="Paste_CanExecute" Executed="Paste_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="Delete" CanExecute="Delete_CanExecute" Executed="Delete_Executed" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>`

Comment: Do you have textboxes or similar within the UserControl, that have the focus at the time you press Ctrl-C? If so then the textbox would capture the command before the UserControl.

Comment: This seems to be a similar problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941707/keybinding-in-usercontrol-doesnt-work-when-textbox-has-the-focus

Comment: I have textboxes but they are collapsed.

Comment: @Anmark - Please could you provide a bit more detail of what is in the UserControl so I can try to reproduce the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me like a charm:

```
<!--COPY-->
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding CopyToStackCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>

<!--PASTE-->
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="V" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding PasteFromStackCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="Copy" CommandParameter="{Binding copy}" />
```