# WPF KeyBinding issues with items in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, key-bindings

I have a problem with the use of key bindings in an wpf application,
but lets start at the beginning:

I have a window which contains various textboxes and a tabcontrol. The tabcontorl consists of two tabs. One of the tabs contains a datagrid with 0 to n items. If the datagrid contains at least one item, the user can remove the selected item from the underlying ObservableCollection.

If I use the buttons I designed for this, everything works fine. But I also want the user to be able to remove the selected item via a key binding.

Therefore I declared the following key binding within the window (the user should be able to use the key binding regardless which control has the focus).

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Right" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding CmdRemove}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

The command to be executed is of type ICommand and bound to the view model of the window.

So now the point where I am lost:

The key binding **only** works, if the tab item has the focus.
**Neither** does it work if the focus is on some other control of the window (then the last selected item should be removed), **nor** if the item to remove is selected directly within the DataGrid.

Am I missing something crucial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your key sequence probably gets "eaten" before it gets to your inputbinding, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941707/keybinding-in-usercontrol-doesnt-work-when-textbox-has-the-focus for a similar problem

Comment: Solved the problems. Thanks!