# How to follow an event or find all its consumers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, visual-studio-2012

I defined a keybinding in my XAML-code:

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" Modifiers="Control" Key="C" />
```

If i press `CTRL+C`, the `CopyCommand` isn't called. If i use the following instead:

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" Modifiers="Control" Key="U" />
```

and press `CTRL+U` the command works fine. 
I think the reason for this is, that the `CTRL+C` gets handled somewhere else and the `Handled` value of the `KeyEventArgs` is set to true, so it doesn't reach my control.

Do I have any possibility to find all consumers for this/any given event? Can I somehow debug/follow an event from the moment it is created until it is consumed?

Simply searching for KeyDown-handlers is not really an option.

I would be fine with using even an external software, e.g. something like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), but would prefer a solution using Visual Studio 2012 or writing code.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but events bubble *up*, meaning that the culprit is likely a child of your window (or whatever it is that owns that `KeyBinding`). What control has keyboard focus when this happens?

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/a/12943306/7486915

Answer (score 0):

Using Snoop I could see that `CTRL+U` gets handled by the UserControl (StructurePanelV) while `CTRL+C` is handled by the Devexpress` TreeListControl inside the StructurePanelView.

[image]

Because the TLC handles the PreviewKeyDown- but the `KeyBinding` listens on the KeyDown-event `CTRL+C` doesn't work (for the order of events please have a look at this article https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/08/07/619-event-sequence-for-the-key-updown-events/).

It seems there is no possibility to define a XAML-KeyBinding as a PreviewKeybinding.

The link provided by Laganimal works fine becaue it also registers on the PreviewKeyDown-event.